# publish artifacts to scp repository if success

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, scp

I'm working on a php project. I want to deploy on the test server if build success. I install the SCP plugin and configure it, but I don't know how to tell to Jenkins to not publish the project if build fail.

How could I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Flexible Publish Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Flexible+Publish+Plugin) in post build steps.

Use Run Conditions to decide whether to publish or not based on the Current Build Status.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution. This is what i'm loiiking for